# Grunt watch with vagrant: HTML pages won't update

Tags: symfony, gruntjs, twig, vagrant

In my symfony project I'm using a vagrant/homestead VM. I use grunt in the host machine to watch changes in SCSS and JS files. If I change a SCSS or JS file, these changes are reflected in my site instantly but when I change a twig template, it may take several minutes for changes to show in my app.

It's become clear that running grunt watch is the base of my problem, but the problem persists long after I stop grunt watch. Could it be possible that I'm watching too many files? How can I fix the big delay in twig template update?

Comment: You can try raising your inotify limit to see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: @Maerlyn I already did that before. I'm afraid that raising it is actually part of the problem and the other part is that I'm watching to many files.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Grunt is watching SCSS and JS files in your project while he is **NOT watching** .twig files. I guess you do not have any tasks in your Gruntfile.js related to these twig files. The changes of twig are not reflected instantly on your app **because of Symfony cache**. Clearing the cache before you refresh the browser could be one of solution.

Comment: Yes, Grunt is not meant to watch twigs because that's symfony's job. Clearing the cache in dev environment is typically not necessary and is also slow because symfony will then recreate the cache before serving my page.